# What is a cookbook or cheat book for this types of multi-variable integrals?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I saw somewhere the following integral:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \Vert x\Vert^3 e^{-a\Vert x\Vert^2}dx=a^{-\frac{M+3}{2}}\pi^{\frac{m}{2}}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{m+3}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{m}{2})}$$

What is a source which lists this types of integrals? A kind of cookbook, which we can look up for this types of multivariable integrals?

If there isn't any handbook, how to solve it?

I searched the Internet, but didn't find any thing.

Comment: Try Paul J Nahin's book ... Inside Interesting Integrals ... to learn amazing techniques to solve these sorts of integrals

Comment: Try Wolfram alpha

Comment: @Bruce, I didn't find any multiple integral$n>2$ in this book. It is a very good book, but I want a cookbook just for reference.

Comment: @Lorenzo, Thank you. Could you explain where is in wolfram alpha is this types of integrals?

Comment: This is the closet I could get it https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+(x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%2B+z%5E2)%5E(3%2F2)+exp+(+-+(x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%2B+z%5E2))+dx+dy+dz+,+x+from+-infinity+to+infinity,+z+from+-infinity+to+infinity,+y+from+-infinity+to+infinity more woflram-fu might be able to get you further. E.g. you might want to convert it to polar coordinates first, and have wolfram evaluate the 1 variable integral.

Comment: @Lorenzo, How to convert a say 10 dimensional integral into 1 variable integral?

Comment: @user85361 Your integral is radially symmetric, so you can compute the integral in the radial direction separately from the rest. E.g. as in here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates

Comment: (I meant rotationally symmetric)

Comment: @Lorenzo, would you please solve it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, let me try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar coordinates, we have the following formula for the volume form:

$dV = r^{n-1} sin^{n-2} ( \phi_1) \ldots sin(\phi_{n-2}) dr d\phi_1 \ldots d\phi_{n-1} = r^{n-1} S dr d\Phi$, where $d\Phi = d\phi_1 \ldots d\phi_{n-1}$ and $S$ is the function of $\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_{n-2}$ appearing in the integrand.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates

Let $f(x) = ||x||^3 exp( - a||x||^2) = r^3 exp( - ar^2)$

Hence $\int_{R^{n}} f(x) dx =  \int_{S^{n-1}} ( \int_0^{\infty} f(r) r^{n-1} dr ) S d \Phi = ( \int_0^{\infty} f(r) r^{n-1} dr ) (\int_{S^{n-1}} S d\phi) = ( \int_0^{\infty} f(r) r^{n-1} dr ) (\text{surface area of n-1 sphere})$.

Wolfram tells us $\int_0^{\infty} f(r) r^{n-1} dr = \int_0^{\infty} r^{n + 2} exp(- ar^2) dr = \frac{1}{2} a^{-n/2 - 3/2} \Gamma((n + 3)/2)$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+r%5E3+e%5E%7B-ar%5E2%7D+r%5E%7Bn-1%7D+from+0+to+infinity

(You could probably do this integral by hand.)

Wolfram also knows the surface area of the sphere: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=surface+area+of+n+dimensional+sphere

Multiplying the two gives us the formula in your question: [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2+%CF%80%5E(n%2F2)+)%2F%CE%93(n%2F2)+*+1%2F2+a%5E(-n%2F2+-+3%2F2)+%CE%93((n+%2B+3)%2F2))

Let me know if any steps are unclear. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I know that  $dv$ formula comes from determinant of Jacobian of the transformation of variables, but I think it will be much clearer for later reading of your good answer to add it to the question.

Comment: Would you please take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858454/how-to-compute-this-multi-variable-integral . Thank you