# How to compute this multi-variable integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I want to compute the following integral:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \Vert x+b\Vert^3 e^{-a\Vert x\Vert^2}dx$$

Where $\Vert x\Vert$ is the norm of $x$?
If $b=0$ then from a paper, I have this
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \Vert x\Vert^3 e^{-a\Vert x\Vert^2}dx=a^{-\frac{M+3}{2}}\pi^{\frac{m}{2}}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{m+3}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{m}{2})}$$

How to compute it? If integration is not possible, what is a tight upper bound for it?

Comment: Wolfy give me: $\int_0^{\infty } \left| x+b\right| ^3 \exp \left(-a x^2\right) \, dx=\frac{2+6 a
   b^2+\sqrt{a} b \left(3+2 a b^2\right) \sqrt{\pi }}{4 a^2}$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk, thank you. You mean Wolfram? How to use it in the multiple integrals case?

Comment: For example put: `integrate(x*y*z,(x,0,1),(y,0,1),(z,0,1))`

Comment: Do you mean $|x+b|^3$ or $(x+b)^3$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I edit the question to be more precise.